# A better way to phrase this sentence, (list of comparisons), without placing unintended emphasis on the first list item?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, lists, phrasing

I have the following sentence...

This power of information, privacy, is the foundation of our ability to have a different relationship with our teachers than we do our friends, our partners, and our parents.

To me, the sentence reads as if the teachers bit is the important part of this comparison, but what I am trying to say is that all of these items are unique.

Comment: "This power of information, privacy, is the foundation of our ability to have different, unique relationships with friends, teachers, partners and parents."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is:

*This power of information, privacy, is the foundation of our ability to have differing relationships with our teachers, friends, partners, and parents.*

If you want to emphasise that all are included you can add 'respectively'.

*This power of information, privacy, is the foundation of our ability to have different relationships with our teachers, friends, partners, and parents respectively.*

Comment: I think the first option is the way to go.